# Best tool for finding text location from .PDF or .DOCX in Python 3.4

Tags: string, python-3.x, pdf, docx, text-extraction

I am currently working on a project where I have to place a digital signature (.JPG file) on a PDF file under the string, 'Comments'.

I want to be able to find the coordinates or location somehow of the String, 'Comments' and then preferably place that signature.jpg several coordinates below it.

Originally, the file is a (.doc) rather than a (.pdf). Would it be easier to find the location of the string, 'Comments' on the (.doc) first and then convert it to a (.PDF)? And if so, how would I be able to find the location of 'Comments' on the (.doc) file in Python?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty tough ask. What you are asking is not just a text search - that part would be relatively easy. But to find the page location you would have to work back from the string to is container, which would possibly be hierarchically nested - like a set of nested html elements - and calculate the position, then add your sig file in at a specified location comfortably below that.

It would be much easier to dictate where the signature is put - maybe have your stationery reserve a location for the signature in the margin, where you know the co-ordinates.

As for the doc option - I thinks its the same issue, but another crazy file format.

Comment: Thing is, each of the documents have the line for the signature at a different place on the page. However as I said, it is always below the word "Comments". I really would like to figure out a way. It's also always the last thing on the page so maybe if there was a way to find the distance from the bottom of the margin to the last word on the docx?

Comment: I completely get what you want and the issues in achieving it. Honestly, it's no trivial matter to do it direct in any useful and robust way. I would look at python pdf libraries and see what options they give. Maybe someone has already provided the 4 things you need: 1) find string, 2) give location, 3) insert image 'below'  location, 4) save file.

Comment: I found something that lets me find the index of a String in the docx file. But I'm not sure how to translate that to a specific position.

Comment: That is really only a small part of the issue. You need something to go through the rendering algorithm to determine the co-ordinates and size of that text, then add your image into the flow at 'nearby' co-ordinates. It's a very complicated problem. I know it should be easy on the face of it, but it aint. Sorry.